# How to get address of running thread from linux core dump file?

Tags: linux, coredump

I have a Linux Core Dump from a multi threaded program.
Usually, I get the stack trace of the ***running thread*** by using '***bt***' in GDB.

But when the **stack is corrupted**, I want to access the thread structures using the **address of thread structures**.

In NetBSD I use _thread_now to get the address of thread structures in gdb.

Is there some command to use for Linux too?

Comment: Can you clarify what it is you are trying to get for those unfamiliar with NetBSD? What do you mean by "thread structures" or "thread address"?

Comment: I mean address of thread structures

Comment: What are "thread structures"? I'm not trying to be difficult, I honestly have no idea what you're asking about.

Comment: Thread structures contain the thread specific data, in linux when we suppose use pthread_set_specific() or similar functions, they are stored in thread structures

Comment: so this might be arch specific. Some archs have thread register and you can get the address of thread struct from that register.. You can check out the glibc code of your cpu

Comment: May be , but it's mostly kernel specific, it's maintained as soft variable and not as a reg.